# How to make sure if a polynomial curve is monotonic under interval [a,b]?

Tags: math, graphics, geometry

If I got a polynomial curve, and I want to find all monotonic curve segments and corresponding intervals by programming.
What's the best way to do this... 
I want to avoid solving equation like f'(x) = 0;
Using some nice numerical ways to do this,like bi-section, is preferred.
f'(x) expression is available.

Thanks.

Add additional details. For example, I get a curve in 2d space, and its polynomial is

x: f(t)
y: g(t)

t is [0,1]

So, if I want to get its monotonic curve segment, I must know the position of t where its tangent vector is (1,0).

One direct way to resolve this is to setup an equation "f'(x) = 0".

But I want to use the most efficient way to do this.

For example,  I try to use recursive ways to find this.
Divide the range [0,1] to four parts, and check whether the four tangents projection on vector (1,0) are in same direction, and two points are close enough. If not, continue to divide the range into 4 parts, until they are in same direction in (1,0) and (0,1), and close enough.

Comment: Why do you say "I want to avoid solving equation like f'(x) = 0" and "f'(x) expression is available"? I can't see what the f'(x) expression could be used for, other than to solve it for 0.

Comment: please do not assume homework

Comment: The difference between f'(x)=0 and f'(x) expression is I can get tangent vector at any position according to the f'(x). f'(x) = 0 means a equation which tell you the position where its tangent is (1,0).

Comment: I can see you're looking for some sort of geometric-inspired approach, and what you propose sounds similar to the geometric explanation for the Newton-Raphson method - but it's not getting away from the fact that you're solving f'(x)=0. Finding the roots of a polynomial is a well-solved numerical problem and using existing work means you'd be done very fast - both in terms of both coding and execution time. What you're trying to do is come up with a new, highly specialised algorithm when there is already a suitable one available - I don't think you'll get an alternative answer from SO.

Answer (score 6):

I think you will have to find the roots of f'(x) using a numerical method (feel free to implement any [root-seeking algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm) you want, Wikipedia has a list). The roots will be those points where the gradient reaches zero; say x1, x2, x3.

You then have a set of intervals (-inf, x1) (x1, x2) etc, continuity of a polynomial ensures that the gradient will be always positive or always negative between a particular pair of points.

So evaluating the gradient sign at a point within each interval will tell you whether that interval is monotically increasing or not. If you don't care for a "strictly" increasing section, you could patch together adjacent intervals which have positive gradient (as a point of inflection will show up as one of the f'(x)=0 roots).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to computing the roots of f', you can also use [Sturm Sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturm%27s_theorem).

They allow counting the number of roots (here, the roots of f') in an interval.

Answer (score 0):

The monotic curve segments are delimited by the roots of f'(x). You can find the roots by using an iterative algorithm like [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).